# Reference table of "tricks" for converting problems to standard LP, QP, SOCP, etc. form?

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming, second-order-cone-programming

Where can I find a decent source/reference that which I can use to look up the various standard "tricks" for converting typical problems to standard form in LP, QP, SOCP, etc.?

The [Charnes-Cooper transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming#Transformation_to_a_linear_program) is a good example of the sort of "trick" I'm referring to, whose job is to do a substitution that formulates a linear-fractional program as a linear program.

Comment: This is a good question! I am not sure there is a single reference. But it would be good to have ;-) There are survey papers for, say, SOCP, SDP, and GP that have useful lists of applications, many of which require some sort of translation.